# What is our stance on questions asking for datasets?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on questions asking for datasets?  Are they on-topic or off-topic?

[Example](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/11488/1652):

> Subject: Dataset of bodybuilding exercises
>
> I am looking for a dataset of bodybuilding exercises that list which
>   muscles are activated for each exercise in a machine readable way.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that would be off topic for the site, as it's not really related to an ongoing fitness program.

Comment: Alright, posted in open data: [Dataset of bodybuilding exercises](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/11488/1652),